# Google Apps API w/PHP and Domain OAuth Credentials

Tags: php, google-apps

Trying to create a function that manages Google Calendar items via PHP for a Google Apps account. Cannot use web client OAuth, all authentication must be server to server.

I did the following in the Google Apps admin panel:

1. Enabled API access for the domain.
2. Created the OAuth key and secret for the domain.

Searched through many tutorials and cannot find anything related to Google Apps, and using the domain oauth key to retrieve user data. All of the examples either require a Service Account or Client OAuth (which is not an option).

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Why can't you do the client oauth once, store the access/refresh tokens, then use those for server to server calls forever?